# Cucumber Selenium - fill in web form

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, cucumber

What's the best way to fill in a web form with lots of text inputs if the project is using Cucumber and the Page Object Model?

For example, let's say the feature file is something like this:

```
Scenario: As someone who wants to sign up
    When I visit the homepage
    And I click on the Register button
    And I enter my firstname
    And I enter my surname
    And I enter my email address
    And I enter a new password
    And I re-enter my new password
    And I agree to the terms and conditions
    And I click the Submit button
    Then I should see a welcome page
```

I understand that the step defs generated by Cucumber would generate a separate method for each of these, which is fine. Would I then have to implement each of these steps in the "RegistrationPage" in its own method? What I'm trying to get at is: is there a way to implement a kind of "fillInform()" method instead of separate methods in the RegistrationPage?

**EDIT:**

The question I asked is probably wrong (I was trying to keep it short). My objective is to be able to do something like this:

```
Scenario Outline: As someone who wants to sign up
    When I visit the homepage
    And I click on the Register button

    And I enter my "<firstname>" in the firstname input
    And I enter my "<surname>" in the surname input
    And I enter my "<emailaddress>" in the email input
    And I enter my "<password>" in the password input
    And I enter my "<password>" in the password confirmation input
    And I agree to the terms and conditions
    And I click the Submit button
    Then I expect the registration to "<ExpectedResult>"

    Examples:
    | firstname | surname    | emailaddress          | password       | ExpectedResult |
    | First     | User       | first@somewhere.com   |                | Fail           |
    | Second    | User       | second@somewhere.com  | .              | Fail           |
    | Third     | User       | third@somewhere.com   | toofew         | Fail           |
    | Fourth    | User       | fourth@somewhere.com  | weakpassword   | Fail           |
    | Fifth     | User       | fifth@somewhere.com   | MissingNumber  | Fail           |
    | Sixth     | User       | sixth@somewhere.com   | m1ssingc4pital | Fail           |
    | seventh   | User       | seventh@somewhere.com | CapsAndNumb3r  | Pass           |
```

Given such a scenario outline, would it still be possible to fill in the registration form using a single method? Something I have thought of (and I'm not sure what the implications of this would be) is to:

```
@When("^I enter \"([^\"]*)\" in the firstname input$")
public void enterFirstname(String firstname) {
    registrationPage.firstname = firstname;
}
```

and then, when the test presses the "Submit" button:

```
@When("^I click the Submit button$")
public void clickSubmitButton() {
    registrationPage.fillInForm();
    registrationPage.clickJoinButton();
}
```

However, doing it this way just doesn't *"feel right"* to me (although I could be mistaken - perhaps it's acceptable?)

Comment: I've not got much experience with cucumber, however have you looked at this: https://makandracards.com/makandra/18905-how-to-not-repeat-yourself-in-cucumber-scenarios

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a combination of datatable and scenario outline to accomplish this.

```
..
..
And Enter form details
    | firstname | surname |.........| password | reppwd |
    | <fname>   | <sname> |.........| <pwd>    | <rpwd> |
..
..

Examples:
| fname  | sname  |.........| pwd  | rpwd |
| Name1  | Title1 |.........| pwd1 | pwd1 |
| Name2  | Title2 |.........| pwd2 | pwd2 |
| Name3  | Title3 |.........| pwd3 | pwd3 |
```

You can use the raw datatable to get the data in the step definition.

```
public void enterDetails(DataTable tab) { }
```

Or create a dataobject(UserDetails) using the headers of datatable (firstname, surname...) as instance variables.

```
public void enterDetails(List<UserDetails> tab) { }
```

Comment: This looks very interesting - I had no idea there was a "datatable" feature in cucumber. Will try and write a test now using what you have described here.

Answer (score 2):

1) Feature file

```
Scenario: As someone who wants to sign up
    When I visit the homepage
    And I click on the Register button
    And I fill the register form   
    And I agree to the terms and conditions
    And I click the Submit button
    Then I should see a welcome page
```

2) Step definition

```
Then("^I fill the register form$", () -> {
    registrationPage.fillForm(user);
})
```

3) RegistrationPage

```
public fillForm(User user) {
    driver.findElement(xxx).sendKeys(user.firstName);
    driver.findElement(xxx).sendKeys(user.surName);
    ...
}
```

There is a issue need to resolve, how to pass down the value for argument `user` for `fillForm()`, you need to consider your code framework, how it store the user data, how it get the user data.  The solution depeneds on self code framework. Not have a unify solution.

1) Solution example when this scenario only test one user:

```
Scenario: As someone who wants to sign up
   When I visit the homepage
   And I click on the Register button
   And I fill the register form with user <userId>
   And I agree to the terms and conditions
   And I click the Submit button
   Then I should see a welcome page

HashMap<String, User> users = xxxxx;

Then("^I fill the register form with user (.+)?$", (String userId) -> {
    registrationPage.fillForm(users.get(userId));
})
```

2) Solution example when this scenario need to test multiple user:

```
Scenario Outlines: As someone who wants to sign up
  When I visit the homepage
  And I register user <userId>

Examples:
   | userId |
   |  001   |
   |  002   |
   |  ...   |

HashMap<String, User> users = xxxxx;

Then("^I register user (.+)?$", (String userId) -> {
    registrationPage.registerUser(users.get(userId));
    // inside registerUser(), should includes the whole proceduce:
    // click register button
    // fill form
    // agree to the terms
    // click submit button
    // verify see welcome page
})
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid doing something like this because I eventually want to convert my scenario in to a scenario outline. I probably should have mentioned this in my question (sorry!). If I convert my scenario into a scenario outline with an "examples:" table, this solution would no longer work, would it?

Comment: Sorry, but I have given the answer to @Grasshopper, because that's exactly what I was looking for. It means that the data exists in a feature file instead of Java code, which makes it easier for anyone (like Product Managers) to modify.